# I'm converting a light switch with Quinetic. Does the light switch need a 16 amp receiver or a 6 amp one?

Tags: light, smart-switch

As above. It's a normal domestic light switch. I want to get one of these: https://www.quinetic.co.uk/products/wireless-switch/

It needs a receiver too, which is wired into where the current light switch is. Does it need a 6 amp receiver or a 16 amp one? https://www.quinetic.co.uk/products/rf-receiver/

Answer (score 0):

Cool idea, I never saw one of those before.  Whether 6A or 16A depends on the size of the load it will be switching.   If it's just switching a light the 6A should suffice.   But considering there is a 5% price difference I cannot imagine why anyone would buy anything other than the 16A one.